# LinkedBlockingQueue .take() performance

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue` that is getting filled by multiple threads, the number of items is big (tens of millions objects).

`LinkedBlockingQueue.take()` takes a lot of time (checked via profiler) - 56% of time.
The queue is never empty!!

What can affect the performance of the `take()` method?

UPDATE:
I did some changes in code that handles the result of the take(), I also placed the take() into another thread, the performance was improved almost by 50%.

I don't understand how this is possible because I didn't change any logic of putters...

UPDATE:

I've counted the number of times queues is full before calling take():
With original code 90%  of calls queue was full.
With improved code 13% of calls queue was full.

Comment: What do you mean by "placed the take() into another thread" - is it possible for you to give some code examples to show what threads are doing what? Is the performance improvement in overall performance or time spent in take()?

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible to put code because the flow is complex

Comment: regarding the performance, the overall time was better because take() is better...

Comment: Do you think that your modifications have changed the throughput i.e. is the queue getting full less often now? In this case the contention caused by a full queue would lessen and improve performance.

Comment: This is what I am checking right now... (i am adding counter before take() that counts when queue gets full) putters are not changed I only improved the handling of the take(), but again, I don't understand how this improvement affects take()?

Comment: @selig, I've updated my post with the counts...

Comment: The queue being full explains why it was slow before - contention on the put lock. Without more info it's difficult to say what's caused the increased throughout but it sounds like you've got a bit of a pipeline going on, which is good.

Comment: what else do you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java/?v=source) we can see that a lock must be taken before taking an element. If lots of threads are taking then there will be contention on this lock - the threads aren't waiting for something to appear but for other threads to take things.

```
 public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E x;
        int c = -1;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
        takeLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            try {
                while (count.get() == 0)
                    notEmpty.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                notEmpty.signal(); // propagate to a non-interrupted thread
                throw ie;
            }

            x = extract();
            c = count.getAndDecrement();
            if (c > 1)
                notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            takeLock.unlock();
        }
        if (c == capacity)
            signalNotFull();
        return x;
    }
```

**EDIT**

In the case where you have one taker and lots of putters and the queue keeps getting full the bottleneck will become `signalNotFull()` given by this code

```
private void signalNotFull() {
    final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
    putLock.lock();
    try {
        notFull.signal();
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This needs to take the `putLock` to signal the fact that there is now space in the queue.

Comment: Is your queue of fixed size?

Comment: yes, the size 100,000 it;s getting filled very fast. the problem is not with "putters"

Comment: @selig, I also updated my post, now the problem got stranger :(

Answer (score 5):

take() is fairly light weight but if you call it enough it will consume lots of CPU.  It sounds like you are passing large numbers of objects which require very little work for the consumer(s).  I suggest trying to restructure you problem so this is done more efficiently.

You can for example,

- use Disruptor which is designed for this sort of problem.
- send blocks/batches of data e.g. a List of objects instead of many individual object.
- use multiple Exchangers (fine for a small number of writers)
- use something like Chronicle if your aim is to persist the data.

It is also possible your profile is not completely accurate.  When you measure small periods of time it can give mixed results.

BTW: the take() is single threaded.  If you have many threads trying to call take() at the same time, they will be blocking each other.